# What is the path for someone who has got "highly skilled migrant" permit to gain citizenship in Netherlands?

Tags: netherlands

If my future employer provides me a highly skilled migrant permit for Netherlands, I am wondering if and how I could get Netherlands citizenship many years later?

If a citizenship is not possible, what is the next best thing (say, permanent residency) one could get?

Comment: This information can easily be found online in the IND website, for example: https://ind.nl/en/dutch-citizenship/Pages/Naturalisation.aspx

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Thanks for the link. I need some more clarification on some of the terms in the document you shared, so I was hoping someone can elaborate the process a little more. For example, the document says, "You live in the Netherlands with a residence permit." What constitutes a "residence permit"? Does a "highly skilled migrant" permit also count as residence permit (I will be living in Netherlands after all)? Or is there a separate path to obtain a residence permit?

Comment: Residence permit is the general category, highly skilled migrant residence permit is of course one type of residence permit.

Comment: @WorldWideWanderer: There is no such thing as a "highly skilled migrant permit" - that's just a category of how you can get a permit. What you hold as a highly skilled migrant is a "residence permit", period.